# Python changing dictionary values in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

Shortest spelling to change dict values is (not using one liners)

```
# process array with loop
dct = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}

for key, value in dct.items():
     dct[key] = 'new'

print(dct)

#{1: 'new', 2: 'new', 3: 'new'}
```

According to python manual `.values()` '*Return a new view of the dictionary’s values*' and [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) is '*provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that **when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes**.*'

Why not other way around, changing view does **not** dynamically changes the dictionary?

```
dct = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}

for value in dct.values():
     value = 'new'

print(dct)

#{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```

Comment: Basically `value = 'new'` simply rebinds the name `value` to point to the string `'new'`. Assignment like `a=b` never modifies the object that was "stored" in `a` before.

Comment: Should we request a change in new version of python or its normal practice to have it that way?

Comment: It has **nothing to do with** the `dct.values()` result and it is very much by design. `value = 'new'` cannot possibly modify a value contained in `dct`, for the same reason that doing `x = 2` and then `x = 3` cannot cause `2` to become equal to `3`, or affect the result of computing `2 + 2` later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically due to the key / value relationship of the dictionary.

In Python, when you iterate over the values of a dictionary using `for value in dct.values():`, the variable `value` is just a reference to the value in the dictionary. When you assign a new value to value, you are only changing where value points to, not the actual value in the dictionary.

Here's a breakdown of what happens:

- In the loop `for value in dct.values():`, value is assigned to each value in the dictionary one by one.
- When you do `value = 'new'`, you are simply changing the reference of value to point to the string 'new'.
- This assignment does not modify the original values in the dictionary dct.

So yeah, to change the values in the dictionary, you need to use the keys to directly access and modify the dictionary values, as you did already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I can give a simple list analogy:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']
for value in lst:
    value ='new'
```

Now, if you `print(lst)` what will you get ?

```
print(lst)
#['a','b','c']
```

Similarly dictionary does not change,

```
dct = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}

for value in dct.values():
     value = 'new'

print(dct)
#{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
```

as commented by @ForceBru

Assignment like `value = 'new'` never modifies the object that was "stored" in `value` before.